# Letter to the Editor

Tags: english, language, cryptic-clues

These are clues to two-word phrases that all have something in common:

1. Sustainable power
2. Fair-haired countess
3. Nice bull’s-eye
4. Furious swashbuckler
5. Quiet spoon
6. Peculiar heirloom
7. Understated whiskers
8. Supervisor of Jesus's crib
9. Violet fruit processors
10. Bug-free iPads
11. Beautiful waves of arrows
12. Weird igneous rocks

For the brave, these are clues to three-word phrases with the same property plus a space:

1. Toner for Yankee photographers
2. Explosive rodent path
3. Huge sleepy rodent #14
4. Menacing desert ptarmigan
5. Underground batters for the 40th Pres.
6. Calvinist singer of "Toxic"

Comment: It may help to clarify what the question is asking. Are we looking for each of the two-word phrases? Or the common property of the group? I guess figuring out one will lead to the other

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Okay, I have most of the 2-word phrases, haven't started work on the 3-word phrases yet.

The rule is the following:

> The second word is an anagram of the first word with one additional letter

So you have the answers:

> 1. Green Energy
> 2. Noble Blonde
> 3. Hot Shot
> 4. Irate Pirate
> 5. Silent Utensil
> 6. Quaint Antique (thanks to Len for "quaint"!)
> 7. Subtle Stubble
> 8. Manger Manager
> 9. Purple Pulpers
> 10. Stable Tablets
> 11. Lovely Volleys
> 12. Strange Granites

This was a blast, looking forward to tackling the 3-words!

Edit: Got 'em all! Thanks to Ben for the extra help!

> 1. American Camera Ink
> 2. Volatile Vole Trail
> 3. Dormant Mondo Rat (thanks to Ben)
> 4. Dangerous Sand Grouse
> 5. Subterranean Reagan Bunters (thanks to Ben)
> 6. Presbyterian Britney Spears

Comment: #3 could be "dormant mondo rat"

Comment: And I think #5 is "subterranean reagan bunters"

Comment: Very nicely done! I have a different answer for "Nice bull's-eye", but yours works just as well. As for "Huge sleepy rodent #14", I hesitate to accept your answer because it doesn't cover all parts of the clue (that is, "#14" is a relevant part of it.) That being said, that clue is one of the hardest and maybe the most forced. If nobody gets it I'll award you the win anyhow.

Comment: "Nice bull's-eye" could also be "Great Target". As for "Huge sleepy rodent #14", it might be "Enormous Dormouse N" (N is the 14 letter of the alphabet). It certainly fits the "forced" category :P

Comment: @Volatility, nice, that's right!

Answer (score 2):

Here's my best guesses so far for the meanings of the phrases. I keep feeling that the title of the riddle is a hint too.

2-word phrases:

> 1. Renewable Resource
> 2.
> 3. Good Shot
> 4. Angry Pirate
> 5.
> 6.
> 7.
> 8. Mother Mary
> 9. Purple Juicers
> 10.
> 11. Pretty Projectiles
> 12.

3-word phrases:

> 1. New Yorker Ink
> 2.
> 3.
> 4.
> 5.
> 6. Reformed Britney Spears

In terms of what the common property is, the riddle's mention of a property and then that same property plus a space makes me think of this:

> "alliteration" and "all iteration"

But if that's the case then some of my guesses above are definitely off.